# How to extend/inherit form_view.js in odoo 15

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

Am using Odoo15 customized in file web\static\src\js\views\form_view.js as below method:

```
form_view.js

      odoo.define('web.FormRenderingEngine', function (require) {

       "use strict";

       process_group: function($group) {

              // custom Code

      }

   });
```

Am extending this file like as mention below:

```
var FormRenderingEngine = require('web.FormRenderingEngine');

return FormRenderingEngine.extend({

  process_group: function($group) {   // custom Code

}

}};
```

.extend or include doesn't work.

please anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the console log you will see the following error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: functions cannot be labelled
```

It is related to `form_view.js` script. To create a new form renderer, you can extend the basic renderer or the form renderer like they did with the [product configurator](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/sale_product_configurator/static/src/js/product_configurator_renderer.js#L7)

***Example:***(extending the basic renderer)

```js
odoo.define('web.FormRenderingEngine', function (require) {

"use strict";
var BasicRenderer = require('web.BasicRenderer');

var FormRenderingEngine = BasicRenderer.extend({
    process_group: function($group) {
        // custom Code
    },
});

return FormRenderingEngine;
});
```

In the `FormRenderingEngine`, you have a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It should end with `});`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your support,

I need one more help.
I have to try to change the place of elements, how it's possible in odoo for the web.
I need to move the search bar to a different location.

Comment: The search bar is part of the control panel, check the [web.Legacy.ControlPanel](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/xml/base.xml#L6) template

Comment: `<t t-inherit="web.Legacy.ControlPanel" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">


<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_cp_searchview')]" position="after">

<div class="myclass">Test Search</div>

</xpath>


</t>`


We add like that.But I need to move the position of search.I move search in to left side menu..the How its possible ?